# Remove-Item Skips Recycle Bin

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am learning powershell, and am curious as to why the syntax `Remove-Item` does not put the file(s) in the recycle bin?

Where do these files go when you remove them, and are they recoverable?

I read the [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article, but did not see anything in there that answered my question, so I ask here.

Comment: "delete" from a command prompt doesn't put them in the recycling bin either, so it's not PowerShell specific. "Why" is only truly known by MS, it's a design choice, but in general the Recycling Bin is for the Explorer UI, not for command shells.

Comment: Also maybe check out [What is the command line way of sending files to the recycle bin?](http://superuser.com/questions/24662/what-is-the-command-line-way-of-sending-files-to-the-recycle-bin), and this StackOverflow question: [How do I move a file to the Recycle Bin using PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502002/how-do-i-move-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin-using-powershell)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I did not know it was this way with all programming.  Thank you for letting me know.  I will read up on the links to get more informed.  VERY intriguing to me, that this is another mystery of Microsoft.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - so theoretically even if the file skips the recycle bin, the file is still recoverable IF it has not been "overwritten" by a "new" file?

Comment: Yup, as long as no data has actually overwritten it, you can usually restore it.