# Auto deleting files older than given minutes on Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, java

I have a folder on my PC in which I keep my temporary files, which I won't be needing after some time. I manually delete them from time to time. What is a way to automate this? I can think of deleting files whose last access time is greater than 20 minutes using Java, but then again, I would have to run it myself which still wouldn't be automation. I using using Windows and file system is NTFS.

Comment: CCleaner has that type of feature.

Comment: If this is so, I would still have to launch it manually and navigate through GUI to do this. But where's this feature?

Comment: With current versions of CCleaner, it is under Options -> Include. When you add a directory, you have the option to delete files and folders that are only older than X hours.

Comment: But that's only for hours. My question says minutes

Comment: Apologies. My misunderstanding. The question title currently reads "older than some hours".

Comment: If you are willing to write a Java program then you can run it periodically using a Scheduled Task.

Comment: How often would I run this scheduled task? Every 20 minutes or every minute?

Comment: This seem to be the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225914/how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-hours-or-minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to delete files after a given number of minutes with no advanced logic, the [GNUWin32 build of the Linux "find" command](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) is a simple option.

**Setup**

- Download the current [binary](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/findutils-bin-zip.php) (findutils-4.2.20-2-bin) and [dependency](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/findutils-dep-zip.php) (findutils-4.2.20-2-dep) .zip files to your PC and extract them as normal.
- Copy the items from the "bin" folder in Dependencies to the "bin" folder in Binaries. You can copy the "manifest" folder items as well but this is not strictly required.
- In the Binaries "bin" folder, rename find.exe to something else (e.g. gnu_find.exe). This prevents confusion with the built-in Windows "find" command.
- Feel free to rename/place the Binaries folder however you wish.

**Use**

Delete all files older than X minutes (e.g. 5 minutes) in a given directory (e.g. TempFiles)

```
gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\TempFiles" ! -mmin -5 -type f -delete
```

Note that the ! (negation) operator is important. Leaving this out will delete files under (less than) X minutes old.

---

*To move items to the Windows Recycle Bin (rather than using *-delete* to remove them directly), please see the "Recycle Bin" section at the end of this answer.*

---

**Options**

- *-name* can be used to filter items. *-name* should always appear before *-delete* or it will have no effect e.g.

  ```
  gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\TempFiles" ! -mmin -5 -type f -name "*text*" -delete
  ```

  In the example above, *-name* matches any file with the sequence "text" anywhere in the file name (including extensions). Use an asterisk (*) for any portion where you want wildcard matching. Asterisks can appear more than once. If matching an exact name, you must include an extension on Windows.
- *-exec ex_command {} +* allows the use of an external command e.g. "ex_command" when eligible items are found. This could be useful for running a separate process (such as a batch file or similar) when "find" matches items successfully. This option should be put at the end of the "find" options i.e.

  ```
  gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\TempFiles" ! -mmin -5 -type f -delete -exec ex_command {} +
  ```
- *-delete* is optional (as are all the options). You can leave it off if you want to preview what "find" will be working on (e.g. for testing or troubleshooting) or simply want a listing of files.
- Be aware that if you are listing files for output, a UNIX forward slash will be placed between the directory name and the file name e.g.

  ```
  C:\Path\To\TempFiles/filename.txt
  ```

Therefore, you may need to take appropriate steps to correct this later.

**Other Options**

If you need fancier options than the ones listed above, you may have to write your own script.

Features vary by language but, as an example, [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) has [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) (current time via the [time module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)) as well as [os.path.getctime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) and [os.path.getmtime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) (Windows creation time and file modification times respectively via the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)). These all return floating points in seconds from an epoch time and make time comparison extremely easy.

As you mentioned Java, you may want to check out this [StackOverflow question on Java NIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033928/how-to-get-proper-file-creation-date-of-file) for similar features.

#### Automation

As mentioned in comments, Windows Task Scheduler can be used to run items periodically, including once ever X minutes. You could use it to run a single-line batch file with the GNUWin32 "find" command above.

You can set increments as small as 1 minute in the Trigger settings for the Windows 7 Task Scheduler. You must type in custom increments e.g. 1 minute manually in the "Repeat task every:" drop-down field, otherwise an item from the default increment list will be used.

[image: Windows 7 Task Scheduler Settings]

Note that while Task Scheduler may be acceptable, one quirk is that it technically starts a task at a given time, then repeats it for 24 hours. This can lead to problems if the computer is not on when a task is set to run.

*To help counter this, you must enable "Settings → Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed".*

**Other Automation Options**

As a suggestion, a tool similar to the UNIX "cron" utility might be preferable. There are a number of better and worse emulations of it, but personally I prefer [IntelliAdmin Cron Service v2.0](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2012/05/free-utility-a-simple-task-scheduler-for-windows/).

IntelliAdmin Cron installs a simple service that runs listed tasks at specific intervals as long as the service is running. It will accept crontab files for scheduling but also has a GUI interface.

One thing to note is that the fields in the GUI interface still expect crontab style entries for specifying times to run. You may want to research this further but the format to run every X minutes is

```
*/X
```

with all other values set to "*". So if we wanted to run a command every minute, it would look like this in the interface:

[image: IntelliAdmin Cron Service Interface]

---

**Time Frames Other Than Minutes**

Time frames other than minutes are of course supported as well e.g.

```
gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\TempFiles" -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

can be used to *-delete* files with a modification time older than 30 days.

**Recycle Bin**

Unfortunately, *-delete* removes items directly and permanently. However, [you can use scripts or third-party executables to send items to the Recycle Bin](https://superuser.com/questions/24662/what-is-the-command-line-way-of-sending-files-to-the-recycle-bin).

[One answer](https://superuser.com/a/912779/302907) to the Super User question linked above includes a link to a homebrew utility called [binit](http://www.akiwi.co.uk/utilities.html). You can use this utility in conjunction with the GNUWin32 version of "find" to move items to the Recycle Bin with the *-exec ex_command {} +* option mentioned earlier e.g.

```
gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\TempFiles" ! -mmin -5 -type f -exec "C:\Path\To\binit.exe" {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Powershell Script + Task Manager:

You can use the following command in powershell to crate the script (Change 30 to how many minutes you want or change Minutes to Hours or Days)

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\folder" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30))} | Remove-Item
```

Once you create the script, apply it to task scheduler.

Comment: This is a great solution, but it has a typo. The `–` character before `Path` is not a valid character... it's an `en dash` which is slightly wider than the `hyphen`. Replace it with a typical `hyphen` (`-`).