# File Retention Policy in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm an avid gamer.  I have a drive dedicated to recordings of my games.  My intention is to just record everything to this 500GB SSD and I only grab something if it's noteable.  To accomplish this, I'd like to set a retention policy on a drive so any files older than... 12 hours get deleted.

Googling this is difficult because of the large number of Windows Server results.  Is there some functionality or software I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Ensure there's nothing else on the SSD that you might want to keep.  Are the video files saved to separate 1 minute recordings, or perhaps separate 100 MB recordings?  What's the hardware and software you're using for recordings?

Answer (score 1):

I would use either a batch script or a powershell script. After you create the batch file or powershell script you can create a scheduled task in Task Scheduler to run it let's say every 1 hour.

But I would probably use this for Command (only in whole days) Prompt:

```
forfiles -p "D:\Videos" -s -m *.* -d -1 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

In Powershell use this command (this will do hours):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Videos" -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {$_.LastwriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddHours(-12) } | Remove-Item -Verbose -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Just replace `D:\Videos` with the actual directory of where those videos are restored. Replace the value `1` with how many days in the Batch Example. Replace the value `-12` with how many hours old (retain the negative) and replace `addHours` with `addMinutes` or `addMonths` or `addSeconds` or `addYears` depending on what you want to do.

Good Luck!

Comment: I would TEST IT first with file copies in an isolated folder!

Answer (score 0):

[I recently answered an extremely similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1230668/auto-deleting-files-older-than-given-minutes-on-windows/1234216#1234216)

In short, you can use the [standalone GNUWin32 build of the Linux "Find" command](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) to delete any file older than X minutes.

**Setup**

- Download the binaries (findutils-4.2.20-2-bin) and dependencies (findutils-4.2.20-2-dep) .zip files from the link above.
- Extract and copy the contents of the dependencies folder to the binaries folder (feel free to overwrite).
- Rename *find.exe* in the "bin" folder (e.g. *gnu_find.exe*) to avoid conflicts with any Windows commands.

Assuming the above rename, the command to find and delete files 12 hours and older would be:

```
     gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\Files" ! -mmin -720 -type f -delete
```

where e.g. -720 represents a number of minutes (60*12 in this case). Do not leave off the ! (negation) option, since without it, files *under* (less than) 12 hours would be deleted.

Note that you *can* leave off *-delete* if you want to simply preview the files it will be working with.

GNUWin32 Find also supports a *-name* option which allows pattern matching with asterisks e.g.

```
    gnu_find.exe "C:\Path\To\Files" ! -mmin -720 -type f -name "text*" -delete
```

**Caveats About Name**

- Be aware that *-name* should always appear before *-delete* or it will have no effect.
- You can use asterisks as you like for pattern matching (including in multiple positions) but be careful about including periods with asterisks (i.e if file extension matching is a concern, just use "filename*" or "*ext"). This has to do with how the Windows command line interprets things.
- You can find specific names (e.g. "filename.txt") but on Windows you must include the extension as GNUWin32 Find consider the whole filename string ("filename" <> "filename.txt")

**Automation**

You can use Task Scheduler to run thing automatically, but as I detail in the very first link, it may not be a preferable option. I personally recommend a Linux "cron"-style application (as detailed in that answer).

**Windows 10**

The above will likely work with any version of Windows, but up-to-date Windows 10 versions should have the ability to run an [Ubuntu Linux sub-system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). "find" and "cron" are extremely basic and should be available with this (though this version of "cron" seems tied to having a window open so may not be entirely suitable for your purpose).